# c++ integer library for 270 digit integers?

Tags: c++, c

I would like to perform basic operations on numbers 270 digits long and I was recommended Matt McCutchen's BigInteger library but I am told it limits you based on what memmory your comp has and my comp has 2.87 GB usable RAM. I want to perform things like division, multiplication etc....any help on what I can use because I don't know yet if my computer's memory will be enough or not.

Comment: How many of these 270 digit numbers do you plan to have in memory at once?

Comment: I'd like to see a library that *isn't* limited by memory in any way

Comment: 270 digits in what base?  In any case, find a library and use it.  All bignum libraries can _easily_ handle 270 digits in any of the common bases.  If you have 2GB of RAM, you shouldn't have problems until you have over fourty thousand numbers with over four hundred decimal digits each.  You're probably fine.

Comment: I can clear 300 digits with 1024 bits, so memory shouldn't be an immediate blocker.

Comment: @CarlNorum I have tried PHP and csharp and wolfram alpha and google but they dont hold precision to I was recommended c++ libraries and knew nothing about RAM or large number computations so I asked for help here.

Comment: `bc` will do it at your command line.

Comment: -1 because 1) doing math ops on a 270-digit number will make it no longer 270 digits, so you need to define this requirement better. 2) there are plenty of big number libraries; why have you ruled them out (or are we to assume you haven't considered any yet, and you're just looking for general recommendations, which would be off-topic?)

Comment: My first computer would have struggled with more than a dozen such numbers. But now thirty years have passed, and you have nearly 100,000 times as much RAM as I had. Don't worry about the odd kilobyte here and there.

Answer (score 2):

270 digits is tiny, relatively speaking - it's under 900 bits. Your computer routinely deals with 2048-bit numbers during SSL handshakes.

BigInteger should work fine. You may also want to check out libgmp (the GNU Multi-Precision library).

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine - 270 digits is not that much in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. 270 digits is *nothing*. 4096 bit cryptography tasks operate on 1233 digit numbers (granted, using modular arithmetic, so it'll never be larger than 1233 digits..) without breaking a sweat.

Comment: thank you everyone for all the actual help. I would only deal with 270 digit number one at a time....Please dont -1 rep me because I dont have knowledge in RAM or math but today I have decided to take on a task many consider insane which is find prime factorization of RSA 896 ^_^

Comment: If that's your goal, you best get reading; [Dan Bernstein has a lot of excellent papers](http://cr.yp.to/papers.html), some of which might be related.